# MVC practice regarding adding targets to UIButton on View

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, uibutton, uiresponder

I have a question regarding best practices when adding targets to a UIButton on a custom view. Currently, I create my UIButton in a loadup method of my view, and assign my view as the buttons target. My view is handling logic when the button is pressed, and it occurs to me that this is not good MVC.

So, I'd rather have my controller provide itself as target and an action for the button, however I'm not sure the best way to accomplish this.

The view could be initialized with a reference to the controller, or could get the controller using UIResponder's nextresponder, and set the target with this reference. However, this could result in circular retains, and would require my view to be aware of the methods that exist on my controller, which is more tightly coupled than I'd prefer.

Alternatively, I could create a setter for each uibutton on my view. However, this quickly becomes unwieldy if I have several buttons, or a view that contains a custom subview with buttons. I could also create properties for each button, but that would also be unwieldy and allows the controller access to more than it needs (it just needs to set targets, it doesn't need to be able to get any reference to the button).

Finally, I could create and add targets to all my buttons within the controller, and pass it to the view on initialization, but that seems to violate the roles of MVC as well.

It seems as if this is a common scenario, are any of these practices considered standard, or is there a better solution?

Comment: What is "a loadup method of my view"?  Is it the view's init method?  Is it the view controller's `loadView` method?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. Its just a custom method I call within init whose purpose is to allocate subviews and place them within my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal belief is that in Cocoa custom views are allowed to have logic and state needed for them to operate, but that they should fully encapsulate the logic and state. That is, you should expose an interface to subviews, but not the subviews themselves. You should expose any private properties or subviews through a combination of delegates and properties as well as custom actions.

That being said, given that you provided no specifics on the purpose of your custom view, it is difficult to provide specifics on the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

It's proper to target the view that owns the buttons. This way, if you need to do any view manipulation (enable/disable, highlight, popup, etc) you're in the right place. Also, only the view will know what the button is, so that, in your action, if you want to check what is `sender`, you can do it. But having your controller know about each individual button would seem to be a more egregious violation of MVC.

It's not inappropriate to have an accessor for your buttons. It can be handy to have the reference around at runtime. If you don't use it, it's hard to argue that there's harm in keeping around an extra `id`. As for hiding them in a private interface, that's fine, but unless you're publishing your API or working with morons, I don't know what harm there is in making the accessors public.

It's proper for your view to have a *weak* reference to your controller, and the button actions can be as simple as invoking one of your controller's methods. It's no big deal, and if you want to add some logic a little later, there's a spot for it.

Sounds like you're doing fine.

PS This is stupid:
[image]